# on my delphi 7 application one part of the code freezes or disables the rest of the things on the form

Tags: delphi, loops, delphi-7

My application should generate a random sum calculate the answer then put it in a edit box on a panel and then the panel should move down and repeat (I have done all of this). OK the problem is while the panel is moving down nothing else works it is as if everything is disabled.

```
unit Unit5;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, jpeg, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, math, Buttons;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Panel6: TPanel;
    Shape1: TShape;
    Panel7: TPanel;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Edit6: TEdit;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    Image5: TImage;
    Edit7: TEdit;
    Image2: TImage;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Image2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
 var hori : integer;
     vert : integer;
     back : integer;
     value1 : integer;
     value2 : integer;
     answer : integer;
     star: integer;
     stranswer: string;
     k : integer;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 panel1.hide;
 panel7.Hide;
 back:=0;
 star:=0;
 end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 stranswer:= inttostr(answer);
 if edit6.Text=stranswer then
 begin
  star:=star+1;
  edit7.text:=inttostr(star);

 end;
 button1.Caption:='Next';
 panel7.Show;
 edit6.SetFocus;
 panel1.show;
 randomize;
 hori:=random(840);
 value1:=random(10);
 value2:=random(10);
 panel1.Top:=0;
 panel1.Left:=hori;
 update;
 answer:=value1+value2;
 edit1.text:=('                '+inttostr(value1)+' + '+inttostr(value2));
 for k:= 1 to 512 do
  begin
   vert:= vert+1;
   panel1.Top:= vert;
   update;
   sleep(50)
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Image2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  back:=1;
  form5.Close;
  button1.show;
end;

end.
```

If you want I can send you a picture of the form.
If you can please help me.

Comment: I see that you're using Delphi7. With the latest Delphi's there's a much more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Im in school this is what they gave us to work in i have heard many times before that the new delphi is much beter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You move the panel down in 512 single pixel steps with a 50ms sleep in between each step. Since you don't process any messages in that time, your app will be unresponsive for the 25s it takes to animate the panel. The program hangs because you have failed to service the message queue.

The solution is to use a timer rather than a loop. In `Button1Click` you need to start the timer ticking.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  .....
  StartPanelAnimation;
end;

procedure TForm1.StartPanelAnimation;
begin
  Panel1.Top := 0;
  Timer1.Interval := 50;
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;
```

The timer procedure is like this:

```
procedure TForm1.PanelAnimationTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoPanelAnimationStep;
  if PanelAnimationComplete then
    PanelAnimationTimer.Enabled := False;
end;
```

These functions would look like this:

```
procedure TForm1.DoPanelAnimationStep;
begin
  Panel1.Top := Panel1.Top+1;
end;

function TForm1.PanelAnimationComplete: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Panel1.Top=512;
end;
```

Comment: @SWeko Well, we can assume that the panel animation was not an accident

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply i really appreciate it.
Now I'm quite new to Delphi so can you please tell me how you i would include this in my code.
I did try putting in your code and including the procedures in the type but it gave me a error saying expected '='but';' found.

Comment: You're asking us to teach you the very basics now. I think I answered the questions you asked. You need to go through some beginner's tutorials.

Comment: Im taking IT as a subject at school and our teacher is not the best and now he dumped this project on us please help me iv searched the internet for more than 4hours

Comment: Put the procedures in the implementation section of the unit. Then put just the procedure headers in the type. And remove the `TTForm1.` when you add them to the type.

Comment: Edit? Craig, you have asked a different question effectively deleting the previous one. Please don't do that.

Comment: @Craig - Since you're a beginner, you could as well put an 'Application.ProcessMessages' after the 'update' call (which is not considered good practice for non-beginners :)).

Comment: thank you it works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
If i may ask why is it not considered good practice to use that command?

Comment: @craig Sertac reverted the question because you had deleted it. Which game my answer no context. When you have a new question, ask a new question. And don't forget to accept answers.

Comment: @Craig - In the code in the question for instance, you can click the button while your panel is sliding. See http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/delphi-processmessages-dark-side.htm to learn why.

Comment: Thanks Sertac it worked im sooooooooooooooooo thankful you cant belive how happy I am :) :) :) :) :) :)

Comment: Do realise that Sertac's hack is not a good solution. It's a hack that gets the job done. Fine for your class I suppose. It always sucks when you sleep in the GUI thread. And you need to deal with all the re-entrancy issues if you call ProcessMessages.

Comment: That's what I was trying to say in my previous comment. Clicking the button while the panel is sliding should not have nice consequences.

Comment: @Sertac Indeed. You still have similar issues with the timer based approach. But I think they are easier to deal with. Plus, no call to Sleep!

Comment: And what happens when you click on `Button1` whilst an animation is in progress. Go ahead and click on it a few times.

Comment: @David Heffernan I got your code to work, but I was wondering how I could make the panel move faster.

And by the way, the way I did it with the application.progressmessages before retrying your code worked and nothing bad happened when I repeatedly clicked the button.

Comment: I found how just change the timer interval

Answer (score 0):

If you want your application do something else while doing the work the above samples are fine. But if you just want that the form is not locking you might use

```
for i := 1 to 100 do   // trying to simulate Sleep(n) in a much more primitive way. 
  Application.ProcessMessages ;
```

instead of

```
Update ;
Sleep(50) ;
```